# What is the reason for initializing self.args when you do class MyException(Exception)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class DeviceError(Exception):
    def __init__(self,errno,msg):
        self.args = (errno, msg)
        self.errno = errno
        self.errmsg = msg

# Raises an exception (multiple arguments)
raise DeviceError(1, 'Not Responding')
```

Beazley: pg 88

> "it is important to assign a tuple containing the arguments to  _
>   *init* _() to the attribute self.args as shown.This attribute is used when printing 
>   exception traceback messages. If you leave it undefined,
>   users won’t be able to see any useful information about the exception
>   when an error occurs."

If i do:

```
try:
 ....
except DeviceError:
 ....
```

here *self.args* is not used since a Traceback is not generated - Correct?
if i ignore DeviceError for some reason, then the *sys.excepthook()* function that is called will need to print a Traceback and will look in self.args - correct?
What does it look for? I mean I'm just stuffing random values in a tuple.. how does the default error handler(excepthook function) know how to display errno and msg?

Could someone explain what exactly goes on with self.args and is it used in Python 3.x?

Comment: "I mean I'm just stuffing random values in a tuple.." - Well don't do that then. Stuff it with something meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is used in the `__str__` and `__repr__` of the base `Exception` type.  Translating from the C source, these are roughly as follows:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ("" if len(self.args) == 0 else
            str(self.args[0]) if len(self.args) == 1 else
            str(self.args))

def __repr__(self):
    return "%s%r" % (self.__class__.__name__.split('.')[-1], self.args)
```

You don't *need* to set `args`, but it means you don't need to write your own `__str__` or `__repr__`.

Also, rather than setting `args` yourself you should pass it to the parent constructor:

```
class DeviceError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, errno, msg):
        super(DeviceError, self).__init__(errno, msg)
        self.errno = errno
        self.errmsg = msg
```

Comment: How did you translate from C source? Or do you mean you read the Python source code and got that snippet?

Comment: @paleywiener I just read the C source online: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1287d4c9cd39/Objects/exceptions.c